# Removing duplicated rows by subset of columns (SQLite3)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Hi I'm recording live stocks data to DB(sqlite3) and, by mistake, unwanted data got into my DB.

For example,

| date | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20220107 | A_company | 10000 |
| 20220107 | A_company | 9000 |
| 20220107 | B_company | 500 |
| 20220107 | B_company | 400 |
| 20220107 | B_company | 200 |

in this table, row 1,2 and row 3,4,5 are same in [date, name] but different in [price].

I want to save only the 'first' row of such rows.

| date | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20220107 | A_company | 10000 |
| 20220107 | B_company | 500 |

What I have done before is read this whole DB into python and use pandas.drop_duplicate function.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("TRrecord.db")
query = pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM TR_INFO, conn)
df = pd.DataFrame(query)
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True, subset=['date', 'name'], ignore_index=True, keep='first')
```

However, as DB grows larger, I think this method won't be efficient in the long run.

How can I do this efficiently by using SQL?

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit 'first' concept in SQL, the database manager can store the records in any order, it has to be specified in SQL. If not specified (by ORDER BY), the order is determined by the database manager (SqlLite in your case), and it is not guaranteed (same data, same query, can return your rows in different order, at different times or different installations).
Having said that, if you are ok to delete any duplicates, and retain just one, you can use the rowid in sqlite for ordering:

```
delete from MyTbl 
where exists (select 1
              from MyTbl b
              where MyTbl.date=b.date
              and MyTbl.name=b.name
              and MyTbl.rowid>b.rowid);
```

This would delete, from your table, any row for which there is another with a smaller rowid (but the same date and name).

If, by 'first', you meant to keep the record that was inserted first, then you need a column to indicate when the record was inserted (an insert_date_time, or an autoincrementing number column, etc.), and use that, instead of rowid.